# Automating Closing and Saving of Excel file

Tags: automation

I am new to vba for excel.

I am trying to automate the closing and saving of an excel file every time it is opened for at least 60 seconds .

So far i have this code. but it does not execute when the file has been opened for 60 seconds unless i manually run the macro. Any help to improve it is greatly appreciated.

`Public Sub Workbook_Open()`

`Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:60"),"ThisWorkbook.TimeOutSaveAndClose"`
             `End Sub`

`Public Sub TimeOutSaveAndClose()
   Application.DisplayAlerts = False
   ThisWorkbook.Save
   Application.Quit`

`End Sub`

Answer (score 0):

This should fix it for you. You have to call the other sub. Also make sure you save it as a macro enabled file

```
Public Sub Workbook_Open()

Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:60"))
call TimeOutSaveAndClose
End Sub

Public Sub TimeOutSaveAndClose()
   Application.DisplayAlerts = False
   ThisWorkbook.Save
   Application.Quit

End Sub
```